# Change approvers on OOB 2007 SharePoint Approval Workflow?

Tags: workflow, infopath

I'd like to be able to change (add/delete) the approvers associated with the OOB Approval Workflow that I have associated with a InfoPath form library on SharePoint 2007.  I want to change the approvers from within my InfoPath form, I do not want to go to change it in the Workflow settings.

Is this possible in SharePoint 2007?  If not, do I need to create a custom workflow?  If so, what would be the high level steps that I would need to take to get something like this set up with InfoPath 2007/2010 form deployed to a SharePoint 2007 form library?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

There are two methods you can use AFAIK:

A. Inject the approvers to the Association Data from code behind.

```
    SPWorkflowAssociation wrkFl = docLib.WorkflowAssociations[0]; 
    site.WorkflowManager.StartWorkflow(itm, wrkFl, wrkFl.AssociationData, true);
```

~Create an **eventhandler**. Make sure you **publish the approver field** from the InfoPath form to a list column (you can also read the InfoPath XML, but requires more code).
~Grab the approver field value and pass it to the **associationData** string.

B. Pass the approvers into the Approvers parameter of the Approval Workflow  during design time

For more info:

- http://www.tonytestasworld.com/post/Howto-Start-a-Sharepoint-Workflow-Programmatically.aspx
- http://blog.symprogress.com/2011/03/sharepoint-2010-dynamic-approvers-for-oob-approval-workflow/